# Redirect logged in user to home page when back button is pressed after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently learning the basics of MVC using codeigniter as my framework and I created a login page. Now I already redirected a user after he logged in and stored a session data but the problem is after I log in (where in I redirected into another page) then pressed the back button the login page still displays unless I highlight the URL in the address bar and pressed enter wherein I go back again to the redirected page. Well I'm aware that this is because of the session check I've made but I need a solution on how I can solve it for the user to not go back again to login page unless he logged out. Same thing for logged out user not to go back to a certain page unless he/she logs in again.

To give a more details what exactly I wanted to happen is just like in facebook login wherein after you logged in and clicked the back button on browser the facebook will still redirect you to your homepage and not on the login page. samething goes to logout.

Well here's my controller so far I think this explains it all. Please do correct me if I made some redundancies in my code and understand that I'm a newbie on this. :)

```
public function index()
{
    $data['error'] = null;
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $data['login'] = $this->login_model->get_login_credentials($username,$password);
    $data['session'] = $this->login_model->get_session($username);


    //CHECK IF THE $PAGE VIEW IS EXISTING
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/login.php'))
    {
        // IF PAGE DOESN'T EXISTS SHOW 404 ERROR
        show_404();
    }

    if(($this->input->post('login')=='Login'&&$data['login']==1)||($username==$data['session']['username'])){
        //SUCCESS LOGIN
        $this->load->helper('url');  
        redirect('news');
    }

    if($this->input->post('login')=='Login'&&$data['login']!=1){
        //LOGIN FAILED
        $data['error'] = "Invalid login credentials.";
    }


    //FOR THE TITLE PART
    $data['title'] = ucfirst('login'); 

    $this->load->view('pages/login/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
```

Comment: back button shows browser cached page.

Comment: so should I clear the cached page? but I don't think that would be the proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already solved here: [Clear cache on back press to prevent going back on login page or previous page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099805/clear-cache-on-back-press-to-prevent-going-back-on-login-page-or-previous-page-a/13099962#comment17804359_13099962) by Hashem Qolami  Same question but in different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

First for checking session data you can use :

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```

here

```
$username==$data['session']['username'])
```

And perhaps you can SET 1 check at the start of your index as :

```
if($this->session->userdata('username'))
redirect('news');
```

Dont forget to load all helpers and libs required before callign those functions..

For sessions check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one later. Will go back on you afterwards for feedbacks.

Comment: Well I already gone back on the code as posted. Well I tried adding your code in index.php page and it returns an error regarding invalid use of $this. I also tried to add up your code in my login controller well still samething happens. I'm not so sure about the loading of all helpers and libs you noted but I think I already done that in the autoload file in config which is this one $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'); correct?

Comment: yes and check the config file (there are settings for the session and a random secretkey which is required)

Comment: well I already setted it up. :) I think that part is needed before you can pass an array to a session data and codeigniter really requires it even if you don't need it as said by the documentations I've read.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to to go to login page after successful login, you can test the session in login page and redirect into some other page if `session` is set. Try this code.

```
if ($data['session']['username']) != NULL) {
    redirect('home_page','refresh');
}
```

Comment: I think as said by the comment above by Arun Killu the back button is yes a cached page based on the browsers history. So the page doesn't reload the page after I pressed the back button. Anyway I also give your answer a try and unfortunately it doesn't do the trick.