# Avoiding page cache on back button press

Tags: php, caching, browser, header

I've done my homework on this and read these:

[easiest way to prevent the back button of your browser from showing secure data after a user logs out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211001/easiest-way-to-prevent-the-back-button-of-your-browser-from-showing-secure-data)

[Clear cache on back press to prevent going back on login page or previous page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099805/clear-cache-on-back-press-to-prevent-going-back-on-login-page-or-previous-page-a)

...but nothing seems to be doing what I want. Essentially, when the back button is hit, I want the page to reload, not the cached version to be served.

I have a form. On submit, the handler page is loaded. Should the user press back for any reason, a piece of content on the form page should not be visible still. I could remove it onunload, but that will look confusing to the user. Better for it not to be there on revisit.

Whatever I try, though, the cached version loads (testing in Opera; I believe Chrome always reloads - could be wrong). This is proven by a JavaScript alert not firing.

Tried (using PHP, by the way):

Suggested by first answer:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Suggested by second answer:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cache control doesnt work as opera and some other browser dont actually recheck the page, but just show it in the last state it was in before you continued. They show it like you never left. Cache will only work if the browsers checks if the page must be renewed. As to a solution, you can only use javascript. See the answer from Bell in your first link for two valid options.

Comment: Thanks. The location.replace option is not an option for me as the page change comes about as the result of a form submission. Removing content before unload had occurred to me, but that's also complicated for my situation. I'll see what I can do - ta.